# VB.NET getting the attributes of a .wav file

Tags: vb.net

How do I get the attributes of a .wav file using VB.NET. In particular, I am looking for a property which has the Duration of the .wav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question:

[How can I determine the length of a .wav file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82319/how-can-i-determine-the-length-of-a-wav-file-in-c)