# How to download audio files (wav or mp3) from HttpResponseMessage Steam Content response in c#?

Tags: c#, httpresponsemessage

My code is below:

```
URL = "https://abcde.com/api//export/1234.wav?type=wav";
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URL).Result;
```

It's showing `"StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent"`

The `StreamContent` is a wav file, and file name is `1234.wav`.
How can I download the wav file from the `HttpResponseMessage Steam Content response` in C#?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: using "HttpClient client", and not use "await"

Answer (score -1):

From within your HttpResponse object there will be a response field. You have several options. What you want to do is use `ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;`

This will output a stream of the content within your HttpResponse message.

Read more about [httpcontent here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks, but could you tell me how to use the stream to download the file? Or I don't need it?

Comment: So, not an expert here with wav files. But if you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502408/opening-an-audio-wav-file-from-a-memorystream-to-determine-the-duration) they use a memory stream to use a wav file. So if you have it in stream file, it's just a process of how do we particularly use our bytes