# Get Sound File Length in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the length of a sound file using this code:

```
MediaElement mysound = new MediaElement();
mysound.Source = new Uri(@"D:\majed\Phone\PhoneProject\PhoneProject\Sound\ring1.wav",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
double length = mysound.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Seconds;
```

but I receive an exception that says "mysound.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Seconds is null"

What can I do?

Note :  I do not want using ( play ) or ( open ) method .

Thank you all

Comment: Try TotalSecond of a TimeSpan

Comment: Have you checked this post out on SO...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82319/how-can-i-determine-the-length-of-a-wav-file-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed NaturalDuration will not be valid till Media is opened : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.naturalduration.aspx 

 I see no way to do this otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.naturalduration.aspx),

> NaturalDuration is not accurate until
>   the MediaOpened event has been raised.

MediaElement inherits from `System.Windows.UIElement` and is in the `Systems.Windows.Controls` 
namespace. By convention, it makes sense that a media player doesn't know certain media details of a file until the file is opened. If what you're after is just the length of a song file, perhaps you can check [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20080801005127/http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=79) out.  Granted, it applies to MP3 files, but perhaps it can get you in the right direction.