# Copying audio files having length more than 5 minutes in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

We have a call recordings for a particular client loaded everyday on to our local server from third party FTP. Now client wants to send the recording files which  are more than 5 minutes to their internal FTP.Is there a way in SSIS where i can select the audio files with more 5 minutes .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, use a script component. Figure out how to do it in C#, and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

in this case i prefere to take the file from FTP to local,

and after with a script task select the file with your condition.

for and examples see this solution

[How can I determine the length of a .wav file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82319/how-can-i-determine-the-length-of-a-wav-file-in-c)